# Getting typescript errors with any

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using typescript.
An error occurs at the "as any" point.
I want to get rid of "any" and add a type, but if I change "any" to a string type, it will not work.
But it didn't work.

tsError

```
Unexpected any. Specify a different type.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
```

```
import React from 'react';
import FacebookIcon ...
import LinkedinIcon ...
import TwitterIcon ...

type Props = {
  icon: 'facebook' | 'linkedin' | 'twitter';
  fontSize?: string;
};

const iconMap = {
  facebook: FacebookIcon,
  linkedin: LinkedinIcon,
  twitter: TwitterIcon
}

export const Icon = ({ icon, fontSize }: Props) => {
  const CompName = iconMap[icon];

  return (<CompName {...({ fontSize } as any)} />) as JSX.Element;};
```

Comment: The above isn’t a type error, but an ESLint error. Why not just pass the prop to the component as a style property: ```<CompName style={{ fontSize }} />```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is a matter of fact that you are not allowed to set `any` as type when casting.

```
return (<CompName {...({ fontSize } as any)} />) as JSX.Element;};
```

I'd rather guess that `{fontSize}` is of type `number` and not `string`.

So try it either this way:

```
return (<CompName {...({ fontSize } as number)} />) as JSX.Element;};
```

Or omit the casting entirely:

```
return (<CompName {...{ fontSize }} />) as JSX.Element;};
```